# automatically add space in input before hitting enter

Tags: python, string, audio, input, space

I have very little experience with python and I believe even my title is incorrect wording. I have a program that plays a note when you type a list of key and hit enter. However for it to work you need to hit the space bar in between each key. I want to get it to accept say eflkjh instead of e f l k j h. How do I do that?

```
soundBinary = input(" > ")
for note in soundBinary.split():

    if note == "q":          #rest
        freq = 37
    elif note == "w":        #b
        freq = 280
    elif note == "e":        #b
        freq = 300
    elif note == "r":        #b
        freq = 320
    elif note == "t":        #b
        freq = 340
    elif note == "y":        #b
        freq = 360
    elif note == "u":        #b
        freq = 380
    elif note == "i":        #b
        freq = 400
    elif note == "o":        #b
        freq = 440
    elif note == "p":        #b
        freq = 460
    elif note == "a":        #b
        freq = 480
    elif note == "s":        #b
        freq = 500
    elif note == "d":        #b
        freq = 520
    elif note == "f":        #b
        freq = 540
    elif note == "g":        #b
        freq = 560
    elif note == "h":        #b
        freq = 580
    elif note == "j":        #high c
        freq = 600
    elif note == "k":        #low c
        freq = 620
    elif note == "l":        #d
        freq = 640
    elif note == "z":        #e
        freq = 660
    elif note == "x":        #f
        freq = 680
    elif note == "c":        #g
        freq = 700
    elif note == "v":        #a
        freq = 720
    elif note == "b":        #b
        freq = 740
    elif note == "n":        #b
        freq = 760
    elif note == "m":        #b
        freq = 780    

    winsound.Beep(freq, rate)
```

Comment: If you don't want spaces, why do you split the string on them?

Comment: Every letter you input has to cascade down that entire list until it finds a condition that is `True`. This is surely better served by a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
for note in soundBinary:
    if note == "q":
        ....
```

Example:

```
string = "abcdefg"
for char in string:
    print char
```

Output:

```
scottsmudger@ns207588:~ $ python test.py
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Answer (score 1):

Two parts to this:

(1) Just iterate through the characters of the input string:

```
for note in soundBinary:
```

This gives you the characters in order, without having to split on anything.

(2) Build a reference dictionary and use it as a look-up list:

```
note_id : {
    'q':37, 'w':280, 'e':300, 'r':320, 't':340, 'y': 360,
    'u':380 # et cetera
}
```

Now, your program uses this in the above loop:

```
for note in soundBinary:
    winsound.Beep( note_id[note] )
```

Does this get you moving?  Putting that reference list at the top of your program makes the actual logic flow a lot easier to read.

Comment: So literally all I needed to do was remove .split(). I searched the web for about an hour before I posted this. Thank you all! I always fell like such an idiot when asking coding questions.

Comment: That's just ignorance, which is corrected by research and asking questions.  Oh, look!  You *nailed* that part!  Remember, most of us answering questions are good at it because we've already made the mistakes you're hitting.  Some of us have made them several times, just to be sure ... :-)

Comment: Also, note that a supportive community gets you some additional feedback and learning.  Don't program in isolation; there's a lot you can learn when you toss your ego into the bottom drawer.  Don't let it out until it has learned to play with others.  :-)